pip >24.0 causes Expected matching RIGHT_PARENTHESIS for LEFT_PARENTHESIS, after version specifier kubernetes (>=9.0.0a1.0) ; extra == 'all_extras'
I am trying to install prefect[kubernetes,azure]==1.4.0 using pip.
It get installed successfully with pip<=24.0.
However with any pip>24.0 the installation fails. For example:
# in a venv
pip install pip==24.2 # released on 2024-07-29
pip install prefect[kubernetes,azure]==1.4.0

results in
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3367, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3147, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 36, in __init__
    parsed = _parse_requirement(requirement_string)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 62, in parse_requirement
    return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 80, in _parse_requirement
    url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 118, in _parse_requirement_details
    specifier = _parse_specifier(tokenizer)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 208, in _parse_specifier
    with tokenizer.enclosing_tokens(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 142, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/_tokenizer.py", line 189, in enclosing_tokens
    self.raise_syntax_error(
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/_tokenizer.py", line 167, in raise_syntax_error
    raise ParserSyntaxError(
pip._vendor.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected matching RIGHT_PARENTHESIS for LEFT_PARENTHESIS, after version specifier
    kubernetes (>=9.0.0a1.0) ; extra == 'all_extras'
               ~~~~~~~~~~^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 105, in _run_wrapper
    status = _inner_run()
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 96, in _inner_run
    return self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 379, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 427, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 239, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 229, in _get_updated_criteria
    for requirement in self._p.get_dependencies(candidate=candidate):
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 247, in get_dependencies
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 247, in <listcomp>
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 401, in iter_dependencies
    for r in self.dist.iter_dependencies():
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/pkg_resources.py", line 247, in iter_dependencies
    return self._dist.requires(extras)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3070, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3369, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3379, in _compute_dependencies
    reqs.extend(parse_requirements(req))
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3434, in __init__
    super().__init__(requirement_string)
  File "/home/lambis/Projects/Prefect/prefect-flows/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 38, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected matching RIGHT_PARENTHESIS for LEFT_PARENTHESIS, after version specifier
    kubernetes (>=9.0.0a1.0) ; extra == 'all_extras'
               ~~~~~~~~~~^


Just to note: you installed a pip version from July 2024, while prefect 1.4.0 is from September 2022. So in that sense, you should use a pip from around that time. Or alternatively, a newer version of prefect: version 1.4.1 has its Kubernetes version fixed.

Thanks @9769953
I mainly wanted to show the pip issue in this question but its good to know that prefect has fixed it, I will use the newer prefect version

Use prefect 1.4.1 instead. It's the last version in the 1.x series, and has essentially only bug fixes with respect to version 1.4.0.
One of those bug fixes concerns exactly this non-existent (and malformed) version of the Kubernetes package; see this pull request for prefect.

Not sure if this is the best solution but I ended up using the latest pip version where I could install the packages. For me that was pip==24.0, installed with pip install pip==24.0. WARNING: Run this only in a virtual environment and not in a global scope
The reason of the failure seems to be the changes introduced to pip==24.1b1 described here

pip has historically allowed many arbitrary strings as versions and version specifiers. Going forward, all versions and version specifiers will need to conform to https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/ (based on PEP 440).

in combination with packages that force an incompatible version name. In my case, the prefect version I was trying to use, uses the incompatible kubernetes version name 9.0.0a1.0 here
